# disable ropemacs in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, pep8, ropemacs

I would like to get pep8 formating in emacs and so I added to my .emacs file:

```
(when (load "flymake" t)
 (defun flymake-pylint-init ()
   (let* ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy
                      'flymake-create-temp-inplace))
          (local-file (file-relative-name
                       temp-file
                       (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))))
     (list "pep8" (list "--repeat" local-file))))
 (add-to-list 'flymake-allowed-file-name-masks
              '("\\.py\\'" flymake-pylint-init)))

(if (file-exists-p "~/ml/.emacs.d/emacs-for-python/epy-init.el")
    (load "emacs-for-python/epy-init"))
```

Now the problem is that ropemacs makes a lot of stuffs which stops me from typing.
I would like to disable it so that I can just get the pep8 formating. How can I do this. I was trying to add

```
(ropemacs-mode nil)
```

to the above lines, but it didn't help. How can I do it?

Comment: I gave up ropemacs long ago. I use jedi instead. and flycheck. I may  write a blog post soon for python setup in emacs.

Comment: I'd suggest that you change the question to "How to disable ropemacs in emacs-for-python?" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the following solution, by not using emacs-for-python and activating flymake on load of Python files with the 'find-file-hook:

```
(when (load "flymake" t)
 (defun flymake-pylint-init ()
   (let* ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy
                      'flymake-create-temp-inplace))
          (local-file (file-relative-name
                       temp-file
                       (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))))
     (list "pep8" (list "--repeat" local-file))))
 (add-to-list 'flymake-allowed-file-name-masks
              '(".py$" flymake-pylint-init)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'flymake-find-file-hook)
```

Comment: I too use emacs-for-python but find rope working too hard and keep me from typing. Guess I'll find sometime to move away from it as well...

Answer (score 0):

Simply comment out all the ropemacs-related bits from epy-python.el will do the trick. ;-)